# it is possible to import package in condition defined in a breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

In eclipse I'm trying to do some modification of a string value, while debugging.
this modification need the use of regex, therefor importing java.util.regex..., 
So I wonder if it is possible to import package in eclipse break point condition editor.
I think that it not possible ( because this part is used just for simple checking, not to manipulate date), but I'm saying that maybe someone has some ideas.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, but you can get around it by fully qualifying any classes that aren't imported in the class that you're debugging. For example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".");
```

becomes

```
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(".");
```